# How to get user Group info in multi tenant app for other Tenant

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, angular2-services, azure-ad-graph-api

I have implemented multi tenant app.Now I would like to restrict some of the groups from other tenant.

For Eg: My tenant aaaaaaa.com. other tenant xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com

So i would like to get "xxxxxxxxxx.COM" user group info and also user info in C#.

I have tried GraphApi for getting other tenant and my tenant user info and group info.but i didn't get solution.i tried like below

```
        // These are the credentials the application will present during authentication
    // and were retrieved from the Azure Management Portal.
    // *** Don't even try to use these - they have been deleted.
    const string clientID = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx";
    const string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    // The Azure AD Graph API is the "resource" we're going to request access to.
    const string resAzureGraphAPI = "https://graph.windows.net";

    // The Azure AD Graph API for my directory is available at this URL.
    const string serviceRootURL = "https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    public async Task<User> userExists()
    {
        Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(serviceRootURL);
        Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
            serviceRoot,
            async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());
        // Look up a user in the directory by their UPN.
        var upn = "srikanth@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
        var userLookupTask = await adClient.Users.Where(
            user => user.UserPrincipalName.Equals(
                upn, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ExecuteSingleAsync();
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        User Userdata = (User)userLookupTask;

        // Show John Doe's Name
        Console.WriteLine(Userdata.DisplayName);
        return userJohnDoe;
    }
```

Any answer appreciated.

Thanks in Advance........!

Comment: Please are more details to your question, links to what you've researched, code that you've attempted, errors your encountering, screenshots, etc. As it stands, the question lacks enough details for anyone to help you.

Comment: Check out these docs on interacting with Groups via the Microsoft Graph: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group

Comment: Hello Saca,I have tried GraphApi  for getting other tenant user group info.but i didn't get solution for that.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you signed in a user from the tenant where you want to get access? You will not be able to read any data from another AAD tenant until a user with access to that tenant has granted your app access to that data. It looks like you are simply trying to use your application to read data from other tenants without gaining consent, which is something we absolutely do not support.

Comment: other tenant users are able to enter into my app  log in with their credentials.But the problem here is that.I have get the group Object ID's for the login user.Please see below i have added more description.Thanks....!